# Renaming a column in a PostgreSQL database table

Tags: postgresql

This is essentially the same question as [How do I rename a column in a database table using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/174582/350713).

So, I want to rename a column in a table. This column is part of a set of tables that lives inside a PostgreSQL schema, which is itself in a PostgreSQL database.

However, I also have constraints like foreign keys involving this column. 
It is not clear to me whether this command will also take care of constraints. If not, how should I handle this?

Alternatively, I also have this database available as a dump file. Would it make sense to edit the dump file, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try it yourself as well, but no: renaming a column won't break your foreign keys.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE a (a_id serial PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE b (a_id integer REFERENCES a (a_id));

ALTER TABLE a RENAME COLUMN a_id TO id;
```

and have a look at `b`'s definition.

Imagine the world if it weren't so: every single column renaming (in my experience happening a lot in the first phases of development) would involve modifying constraints here and there.  Wouldn't make much sense, would it?

Doing this in a dump is rather error-prone, I would not do that.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I did try it, and it seemed to work, but I wasn't sure if this was a reliable procedure in general.

Comment: So, if it doesn't break, what are the fkeys attached to?

Comment: @Qwerty I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  Otherwise, the column that is referencing a column of another table is shown in the `pg_catalog.pg_constraint.conkey` column (the number in that array itself referencing `pg_attribute`).  No column name is involved in this.

Comment: @dezso I was asking about the unique identifier used to attach the fkeys to, if it doesn't use the name. But I did little research on it already, so I am K. Thanks.